# what version of RHEL is MongoDB 2.0.1 certified on?

Tags: mongodb, rhel, rhel5

Could anyone please tell me what version of RHEL is mongoDb certified on?

Answer (score 0):

There are users running on various 5.x and 6.x, so any of these should be good, although I would suggest the later versions of 6 as opposed to 5 if possible.